# Рекурсивное удаление файлов

Tags: windows, cmd

Есть папка, в папке другие папки. Там хранятся файлы `*.wow`. Как просто из командной строки  Windows  все их удалить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать так

```
del /S /P *.wow
```

**/S** - флаг говорит, что будет удаляться всё рекурсивно в данной папке

**/P** - флаг говорит о том, что надо спрашивать юзера о подтверждении удаления, если не надо, то команда без него

```
del /S *.wow
```

Comment: спасибо, работает